# Is this atmospheric composition breathable on a planet with 50% more surface pressure?

Tags: hard-science, atmosphere, biochemistry

I've read all the related questions on here and as far as I can tell this should be breathable on my planet Liskuel, which has 1.5 bars of pressure. However, I'm really bad at maths and don't really know how to scale it up with atmospheric pressure, so I would really appreciate a fact check.

***Edit: I've updated the stats to match some feedback I got, but just so the original answers make sense, here are the original stats:***
[image]

***...And here are the updated stats (more oxygen and water vapour):***
[image]

*Additional query:* I've included a fair amount of Xenon - do you think there is enough to accumulate in the lowest valleys and knock out your average human?

Comment: Breathable for how long?

Comment: Your water-vapor content is way to high. Earths standard one is 0.0025 atm. Sure, it does varry between 0 and 0.04 atm, but thise are extremes. You'll usually find out the maximum possible water content via calculating the [water vapor saturation pressure](https://www.engineeringtoolbox.com/water-vapor-saturation-pressure-air-d_689.html). Calculate your planets global average temperature and multiply it with 0.25. Thats the average water content of your atmosphere.

Comment: @Ash incessantly.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight That's wonderful information, thank you! Do you have any tips for calculating the global average temperature? I will of course do my own research, so feel free to ignore.

Comment: Firstly I messed up with the aproximation formula. Multiply with 0.125, not 0.25. [Planetary equilibrium temperature](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planetary_equilibrium_temperature) is a good starting point to get a planets temperature. I prefer the stellar temperature based equation. [This video](https://youtu.be/y3Kb_ik5f-I) is very useful for determining the albedo of your world.

Comment: The greenhouse effect is tricky as I already pointed out in my answer. I tried a lot of different approaches, but I settled with just looking at the ammount of greenhouse gases and adding a teperature I consider plausable. Mars has 3K, Earth 33K and Venus ca. 400 K. Just don't go crazy and don't go over 47 C global temperature, as this is the point where a runaway greenhouse effect occurs. That said planets with little to no surface water can take higher temperatures, a there is little water to evaporate.

Answer (score 7):

What matters for breathability is the partial pressure of the gas.

According to [Dalton law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalton%27s_law)

$Partial\ Pressure = Total \ Pressure \cdot volume \ fraction$

For Earth

$P_{O_2}=1 [bar]\cdot 0.21=0.21 \ bar$

On your planet

$P_{O_2}=1.5 [bar] \cdot 0.055=0.08 \ bar$

That's a tad more than the partial pressure in the [Death Zone on Mount Everest](https://simple.wikipedia.org/wiki/Death_zone)

> at the top of Mount Everest the average person takes in about 30% of the oxygen in the air that they would take in at sea level; a normal human person used to breathing air at sea level could only be there for a few minutes before they became unconscious.

Therefore the atmosphere of your planet is at the limit of breathability, and would require proper acclimation to not be lethal.

That apart, it is also pretty dry, which is an additional issue, though not impacting breathability.

After your edit:

$P_{O_2}=1.5 [bar] \cdot 0.105=0.16 \ bar$

which is breathable, comparable to what we breathe when we are on a mountain.

Comment: @MissMermaid, FYI this is not a forum: on a forum you post a question, get answer, change the question and so on in a potentially endless loop. Here one posts a question, gets an answer and that's it.

Comment: Ah, gotcha. Sorry!

Answer (score 5):

Probably breathable but almost certainly dangerous:

- The [recommended 8 hour Ozone exposure](https://www.epa.gov/indoor-air-quality-iaq/ozone-generators-are-sold-air-cleaners) is at most 0.1ppm, that's a thousandth of your atmospheric concentration. Given that [studies](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK430751/) have shown that tiny increases of just 0.001ppm cause notable increases in fatalities this is almost certainly a sizeable problem in a continuous exposure scenario.
- The other thing that makes this situation dangerous is the fact that breathing that much Nitrogen under that much pressure is the equivalent (1.245bar post edit) of being in a constant [SCUBA dive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scuba_diving) at a depth of roughly 6 metres, while many people will notice little to no effect from this, [at least initially](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dysbaric_osteonecrosis), many others will be immediately, if lightly, impaired (approximately the equivalent of drinking two thirds of a martini an hour). As the long term build up, over days or weeks instead of hours, of dissolved Nitrogen in the blood is not a well understood phenomena the effects of this may lessen or worsen over time.

To address the Xenon issue, no probably not, [Xenon anesthesia](https://anesthesiology.pubs.asahq.org/article.aspx?articleid=1945725) is only effective in a 70/30 mix of Xenon to pure Oxygen there's simply not enough of it to concentrate to that degree. Having said that in combination with the mild narcotic effects of the Nitrogen and its oxides lower concentrations may prove to have some effect.

Answer (score 0):

As for the breathability of the atmosphere. I encountered this list in a [video by worldbuilding YouTuber Artifexian](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9-j_JOWPLj8) and have added to it since. I did check several values and found them to be correct. Going down the list it became increasingly difficult to verify the values, so take everything without a link with a grain of salt.

- N2 < [3 atm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nitrogen_narcosis)

1.25 atm, o.k

- CO2 < [0.02 atm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_dioxide#Toxicity)

0.015, o.k

- CO < [0.0001 atm](https://www.uptodate.com/contents/carbon-monoxide-poisoning)

not found

- CH4 < 0.05 atm (not toxic, but [explodes at this point](http://aetinc.biz/newsletters/2010-insights/october-2010))

0.00045 atm, o.k

- SO2 < 0.000005 atm

not found

- O3 < [0.0000001 atm](https://www.epa.gov/indoor-air-quality-iaq/ozone-generators-are-sold-air-cleaners) i.e. 0.1ppm

0.000165 atm, exceeded by 3 orders of magnitude

- O2 < 0,16 – 0,5 atm ([0.3 - 0.35 atm wildfire limit](https://www.earthmagazine.org/article/flammable-planet-fire-finds-its-place-earth-history)) [For the maximum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oxygen_toxicity) [and this](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/0/04/Pulmonary_toxicity_tolerance_curves.svg/1024px-Pulmonary_toxicity_tolerance_curves.svg.png) and [for the miniumum](http://www.geography.hunter.cuny.edu/tbw/wc.notes/1.atmosphere/oxygen_and_human_requirements.htm).

0.1725 atm, low but o.k

- Ar < 1.6 atm

0.00006 atm, o.k but very low, see below

- NH3 < [0.0001 atm](https://www.ucl.ac.uk/~ucbcdab/urea/amtox.htm)

not found

- Xe < 0.21 atm

0.00135 atm, o.k I would be surprised if anyone would even notice, nevermind get knocked out.

There is surprising little Argon in the atmosphere.

> Nearly all of the argon in the Earth's atmosphere is radiogenic argon-40, derived from the decay of potassium-40 in the Earth's crust. In the universe, argon-36 is by far the most common argon isotope, as it is the most easily produced by stellar nucleosynthesis in supernovas. - [Wikipedia](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argon)

Argon isn't in the atmosphere by chance but as a result of the alpha decay of potassium-40. This means that the planet is either very young (not older than maybe 0.5 byr at most), in a low metallicity system (meaning it would most likely be a planet dominated by water), lost its original atmosphere in a geographically speaking recent event, is an artificial world around a gas giant or black hole or is so small (moon-sized) that it had little radioactive material, to begin with. If none of these assumptions are correct, I suggest adding argon.

And you are going to have one hell of a [greenhouse effect](https://www.science.org.au/curious/earth-environment/enhanced-greenhouse-effect) CO2(factor of 4.5), H2O (factor of 24), CH4 (factor of 3), NO3 (factor of 4.5), O3 (factor of 41.25) and H2 (no direct effect, yet it increases the lifetime of other gases) are relevant for the greenhouse effect. Ignoring anything but H2O and CO2, which are responsible for most of Earths greenhouse effect (this is not really a clean approach as you added even more of the minor and stronger greenhouses gases) we see that you increased those by a combined factor of 66. Now calculating greenhouse effects is really hard and [requires simulation programs](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_model), but it is save to say that it will be way higher than Earths 33 K. Maybe 150 K? Now you are either dealing with a planet with a [runaway greenhouse effect](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Runaway_greenhouse_effect), which is on the way to become an exo-Venus or one still habitable but near the outer edge of the habitable zone. In Solar system terms, this means out beyond Mars or even in the asteroid belt.

Where does this leave us? Ozone is way too common but it might still be fine because ozone is usually found in the [ozone layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_layer) and not in the troposphere. The greenhouse effect might turn the planet into a cooking-pot. Then the air won't be breathable because it will boil you alive. Avoid getting the planet hotter than 47 °C to avoid the greenhouse effect. So apart from this, the fact that there is an odd lack of argon and that your greenhouse effect will be enormous compared to Earth the atmosphere is breathable.

Comment: Very informative answer. But the OP is asking if the atmosphere is breathable, and that point is not touched at all here. Moreover, being a hard science question, citations are expected.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/62109)

Comment: @Ash Currently editing to meet requirements, do not delete.

Comment: @Ash Edit it to fit question.

Comment: @L.Dutch Edit it to fit question.

Comment: You are answering "is the planet livable?", which is not the OP's question.

Comment: You have ignored the values given in your own link concerning ozone toxicity.

Comment: @Ash I just messed up the number of 0's.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight Not just that, the fact that according to the [original linked source](https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/books/NBK430751/) increases of as little as 10 parts per _billion_ of atmospheric ozone exposure cause noticeable increases in mortality rates, more than 1% in terms of total deaths.

Comment: @L.Dutch I do answer OP's question about the breathability, the xenon and give an extended fact check. There I encounter the high concentration of greenhouse gases and the low concentration of argon. I remark on them and discuss their implications. Yes, I go on tangents but some extra information does not hurt anyone. For an analysisis of livability I would need way more data: age, surface composition, mass, radius, mass of parent star, orbital prameters... thus I couldn't possibly asses the planet's livability.

Comment: @Ash, I linked the wrong source. NOW everything is fixed. The source you discuss was about the increase of mortality for an increase of O3. As soon as there is any mortality I do not consider the atmosphere breathable.

Comment: @Ash Thanks for the fix and critique. Those pesky small numbers... Is the post no longer under threat of deletion?

Comment: There's apparently no way to withdraw a delete vote @L.Dutch is that right?

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight Mortality is part of life in general it's whether the atmosphere is immediately unbreathable or not that is at issue, I'm still not sure if you've answered that question or not here but I'm happy to let the answer stand as it is.

Comment: @Ash [Mortallity isn't always part of life](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Turritopsis_dohrnii). So how do you define "breathable"? Sure, you can breath even a 1 atm O3 atmosphere, you'll just drop dead on the spot. By this definition only vacuum, solids and low viscosity liquids are not breathable. I would say that if you can breathe it indefinitely (or for say 50 years) without dying it is breathable.

Comment: @TheDyingOfLight You need to actually address the issue of ozone toxicity.

Comment: @Ash O3 < 0.0000001 atm i.e. 0.1ppm
0.000165 atm, exceeded by 3 orders of magnitude AND Ozone is way too common but it might still be fine because ozone is usually found in the ozone layer and not in the troposphere. What else should I say? I did not say ok and remarked on it.

Comment: "exceeded by 3 orders of magnitude" and "is way too common" don't actually address the effects that that concentration of ozone may have on a population trying to breath this atmosphere.

Comment: @Ash I see. I'll research it this evening.

Answer (score -1):

I have not done the maths, but using common sense and some research I have got you an answer. At 5% oxygen concentration on earth, with one bar of pressure, you start to die, although with 1.5 bars of pressure you would definitely survive. It seems (at least with my understanding) that with a 5.5% percent concentration of oxygen would act like 8.5% concentration of oxygen. This concentration is normally not enough for a human to survive, although it is likely that we would be able to adapt by increasing the amount of hemoglobin in their blood. 
There also doesn't seem to be enough water, which could lead to a lot of deserts. 
hopefully, my math is correct and I have helped you with this. 
edit: I actually did the math, and didn't plan to at the start so I wrote it wrong. sorry.
https://www.thenakedscientists.com/forum/index.php?topic=44734.0 source for the amount of oxygen needed

Comment: The question is tagged hard science. doing the math would help.

Comment: I did do the math, I just forgot to fix it.